# Generators of cyclic group of finite fields

Tags: polynomials, fields, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field and $f(x)\in F[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$. So $E:=F[\alpha]$ is a finite field of order $|F|^{n}$.

We know that $(E^{\ast},.)$ is cyclic group of order $|F|^{n}-1$. My question is that what can we say about generators of $(E^{\ast},.)$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $f(x)$? Can we explicitly find a generator with respect to $\alpha$ and $f(x)$?

> For example, if $|F|=2$ and $2^{n}-1$ is prime number, then $\alpha$ is a generator (actually each non-identity element in $E^{\ast}$ is a generator.)
>
> If $|F|=2$ and $f(x)=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$, then order of $\alpha$ is $5$, which means that $\alpha$ is not a generator of $(E^{\ast},.)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly" finding $a$? No, I don't think there is some magic formula for it; one needs to do computations, generally speaking. There is a special class of irreducible polynomials, called primitive, for which any root has maximal period. Again, there is no generally known formula how to find such polynomials.

Comment: Can we  find explicitly a generator of $F^*$?

Comment: @abx: To repeat Dima's question: what exactly do you mean by explicitly find?

Answer (score 2):

See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polynomial_(finite_fields). There is plenty of theory and practice in the area, going back to Richard Parker.